# Changing a label in prepareforsegue

Tags: swift

I have a issue with writing the swift code inside of the prepare for segue. I wrote code just to transfer the writing inside of my text box to a label on another view, but this crashed when I went to the other page.

```
var motionMovement : SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController   
motionMovement.laBel.text = teXt.text
```

Then I added added this to not make it crash

```
if segue.identifier == "hi"{
        var motionMovement : SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
        motionMovement.laBel.text = teXt.text
    }
```

But now it doesn't change the label.

Comment: Where does it crash on the other page? What line of code?

Answer (score 4):

The outlet wasn't be allocated when you use it in `prepareForSegue:` .You must create a `String` variable in `SecondViewController` to store the label text in `prepareForSegue:` and then in the `viewDidLoad` in `SecondViewController` set it to the desired `UILabel`

in `SecondViewController`

```
var labelString: String?
viewDidLoad() { 
     laBel.text = labelString
}
```

and on prepareForSegue

```
if segue.identifier == "hi"{
    var motionMovement : SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
    motionMovement.labelString = teXt.text
}
```

Comment: now that I have done that it blanks out the label no matter what.

Comment: @tom3377, In my experience, the value-assigning should be in `viewWillAppear` rather than `viewDidLoad`. Hope this still helps you