# Label Outlet can not edit by other view Controller in swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

i wanted to change the login screen userName Outlet but its not working i can not find our the solution

```
    let loginVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
    if self.emailTextField.text == "" {
        loginVC.userName?.text = "Hello"
    } else {
        loginVC.userName?.text = self.emailTextField.text!
    }
    navigationController?.pushViewController(loginVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29422095/changing-a-label-in-prepareforsegue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let loginVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
if self.emailTextField.text == "" 
{
    loginVC.str = "Hello"
} 
else 
{
    loginVC.str = self.emailTextField.text!
}
navigationController?.pushViewController(loginVC, animated: true)
```

**LoginViewController**

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController 
{
    var str:String! = nil
    override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.userName.text = str
    }
}
```